# jQuery best practice to detect html element changes

Tags: jquery

I have two code options that are working fine, but I would like to know what is the best option to use, assuming that I will have a couple of this script to fire at same time sometimes in a high traffic website.

The code is to limit input checkboxes selection, the below scripts is for only 1 section but I will have 4 or more sections in each page to check at the same time (I still coding on loop checking, so here is just one section).

### OPTION 1

```
    jQuery( function($){
        var max_opcoes = 2;
        var inputs_opcoes = "div.wc-pao-addon-container:has([data-addon-name='Opções']) input";
        $('body').on('change', inputs_opcoes, function(){
          var $inputs_opcoes = $(inputs_opcoes);

          if($inputs_opcoes.filter(':checked').length == max_opcoes) {
            $inputs_opcoes.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $inputs_opcoes.filter(':checked').removeAttr('disabled');
          } else {
            $inputs_opcoes.removeAttr('disabled');
          }

        });
    
    });
```

### OPTION 2

```
jQuery( function($){
    var onDomIsRendered = function(domString) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            function waitUntil() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if($(domString).length > 0){
                        resolve($(domString));
                    }else {
                        waitUntil();
                    }
                  }, 100);
                }
            //start the loop
            waitUntil();
        });
    };

    onDomIsRendered("div.wcpt-product-form.wcpt-modal").then(function(element){
        
        var max_opcoes = 2;
        var $inputs_opcoes = $("div:has([data-addon-name='Opções']) > input");
                        
        $inputs_opcoes.change(function() {
        //$( $inputs_opcoes ).on( 'change', function() {

          if($inputs_opcoes.filter(':checked').length == max_opcoes) {
            $inputs_opcoes.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $inputs_opcoes.filter(':checked').removeAttr('disabled');
          } else {
            $inputs_opcoes.removeAttr('disabled');
          }
        });
```

### So, the basic difference in both codes are:

```
$('body').on('change', inputs_opcoes, function(){
    (... function here ...)
```

and

```
    var onDomIsRendered = function(domString) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            function waitUntil() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if($(domString).length > 0){
                        resolve($(domString));
                    }else {
                        waitUntil();
                    }
                  }, 100);
                }
            //start the loop
            waitUntil();
        });
    };

    onDomIsRendered("div.wcpt-product-form.wcpt-modal").then(function(element){
    (... function here ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't use setTimeout like that because it uses the CPU every 100 milliseconds and I don't see the point anyway since from the looks of it by the time it reaches onDomIsRendered, jQuery's ready event has already been fired so what's the point?

Another observation is that you should use prop and not attr because it is faster. You can also speed it up by replacing "body" with document.body and by saving your first call to $inputs_opcoes.filter(":checked"). Here is what I mean:

```
jQuery( function($){
    var max_opcoes = 2, inputs_opcoes = 'div.wc-pao-addon-container:has([data-addon-name="Opções"]) input';
    $(document.body).on("change", inputs_opcoes, function(){
        var $inputs_opcoes = $(inputs_opcoes), $checked = $inputs_opcoes.filter(":checked");

        if ($checked.length == max_opcoes) {
            $inputs_opcoes.prop("disabled", true);
            $checked.prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $inputs_opcoes.prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Promise is also not available in older browsers. If you really need to use that use jQuery's $.Deferred() which is good enough for something as simple as that. And use MutationObserver instead of setTimeout.